# Method to get all items with `where` and pivot table[Laravel 5]

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot-table

I need to get all items where `project_group.admin_id'` equal to current user id.

This `find` method will return just one item:

```
$projects = Group::find(1) -> projects()->where('project_group.admin_id', '=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Is there any why to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer:

```
public function userProjects(){

            $adminIdCondition = function($q){
                        $q->where('admin_id', Auth::user()->admin_id);
                    };
            $projects = Project::with(['groups' => $adminIdCondition])
                        ->whereHas('groups', $adminIdCondition)
                        ->get();

             return $projects;
        }
```